# Same coordinate Systems in QGIS with different extents

Tags: qgis

I have a polygon shape file and a points shapefile on the same coordinate system in qgis but completely different extents. How do I fix this?

Massachusetts is in wrong place both using NAD83

[image].

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data and it's projections it's hard to be sure, but the most likely problem is that one of your data sets is in Massachusetts State Plane feet and the other is in Massachusetts State Plane metres.

Whatever the projections you've been given they clearly are not the same.